# Stacked bar charts ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataframe similar to the following

```
A  B  C
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b3 c3
a4 b4 c4
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart where the x-axis is A and the bar is made up of two stacks of height B and C a top each other. i.e the bar for a1 will be stack bar with stacks of height b1 and c1. (Total bar height = b1+c1)

I am using code like

```
ggplot(dataframe) + geom_bar(aes(x=A, y=B), stat="identity") + geom_bar(aes(x=A, y = C), stat="identity")
```

ggplot2 documentation says

> By default, multiple x's occuring in the same place will be stacked a top one another by position_stack.

However when I execute my code, the stacking does not happen a top one another. But both stacks begin at the X-axis. Due to this the higher stack overlaps the smaller stack. The height of plotted bar is  max(b1,c1)

I have seen the recommendation to use melt() to achieve what I am trying to do, but I was wondering if this is possible without melt, just using ggplot/geom_bar

I am new to R and I am new to stack overflow. Hopefully I have been able to explain my query.

Comment: `melt` your data. A single `geom_bar` will stack different bars (identified as separate via a `group` or `color` or `fill` aesthetic). Two different `geom_bar` calls are not aware of each other.

Comment: I (or someone else) would be happy to demo if you share a reproducible example. Essentially the answer to *"I was wondering if this is possible without melt, just using ggplot/geom_bar"* is "no". `ggplot` is built to work with "tidy" data, and your data is not tidy.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I will go the melt way then.